# How to save Terminal Output to image file with convert imagemagick

Tags: terminal

I wanted to save Terminal output to an image file so i googles alot but i didn't find alot then found some blogs that says you can save output in image using convert command provided by ImageMagick
so I tried the command

I tried the command

ip a | convert label:@- ip.png

but the image always created with"@"
see the below image for issue
[Imagemagisk-Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtBvN.png)

Then I tried to run script as well
but same issue

command: convert label:test.sh- ip3.png
[Script-output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xz3y2.png)

Comment: Check your Imagemagick policy.xml file to see if you have permission to use @ syntax.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm having the same issue, and I've checked the policy.xml and commented out the @ restrictions.